# Do Eggs Need to be Refrigerated?

Tags: eggs, storage-lifetime

Do eggs really need to be refrigerated? If so, how long can they last without refrigeration? Obviously eggs come out of the chicken at body temperature, so there must be some amount of time they can survive without spoilage.

I once attended a catering school in Hungary, and families there store eggs at room temperature for days with no (apparent) ill-effects, particularly in rural areas. But the idea seems anathema to almost everyone in the US.

Answer (score 1):

As an American living in Europe, I understand the horror associated with non-refrigerated eggs.

However, I can assure you from my own experience, that if the eggs are fresh from a farm, unwashed, and stored in a cool location, they can last up to a month. (This is my preference, as the eggs taste far fresher.)

It is common practice here to find eggs simply sitting on the shelves of grocery stores without the benefits of refrigeration and the majority are unwashed eggs. I have used such eggs up to 10 days past the expiration date with no ill effects.

Best of luck.